# SwiftUIのscrollviewで、初期表示の位置を設定する方法について

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

**質問内容**
SwiftUIで作成したスクロールビューの、初期表示位置を設定する方法について教えていただきたいです。

以下コードのように、ScrollViewReader{}を用いることで、
一旦、一番上（縦スクロールの場合）を表示し、その後ボタンを押すと所定のidを持つビューまで移動できるようなコードを作成できました。

しかし、やりたいことは、最初にビューを表示する時点で、指定のビューが真ん中に来るようにすることです。
私の希望する挙動はSwiftUIでできるでしょうか？

**試したコード**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            Button("設定した数字へスクロール") {
                scrollView.scrollTo(50, anchor: .center)
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                        Text(String(index))
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 15)
                            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                            .id(index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問の件、自己解決いたしました。　.onApper()をscrollViewに付与することで、期待した動きを実現できます。